# How to set the published SWF name in Flash Builder project

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I have been working happily in FlashDevelop for years and purchased a Macbook recently. I've decided it's better to use Flash Builder while using my Macbook. I've got everything set up short of the published SWF name. It seems to force me to use the name that the Application Class has. In my example this name is "Main.as". I wish the published SWF to be named "activityShell.swf" several reasons I will not get into here.

Please tell me how during build and debugging do I get the published swf to be called activityShell.swf and not Main.swf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please tell me how during build and debugging do I get the published
>   swf to be called activityShell.swf and not Main.swf?

You can change the name of your main application file (AKA Rename Name.as to activityShell.swf ).  That may give a warning since activityShell does not follow standard naming conventions for class names.  The first letter of a class is usually a capital.

Or you can change the name of the generated SWF after the fact.

Or you can use the output [command line argument](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html) to specify the file name and location of the finished SWF.

Comment: So the answer is I can't change the publish name without changing the classname?

Comment: Allow me to correct myself.  There is a compiler argument named output; which should do you what you want.  I'll update my answer: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html

Comment: However, I've just learned that -output is disabled within Flash Builder and can only be used when building from the command line.